# Working with windows applications remotely

Tags: windows, xming

I am working with some applications which are located on remote windows server. In that case I need to login remotely to this machine (using remote desktop). Having two desktops (local and remote) on one monitor is uncomfortable (I need to all the time switch between them).

Is there any similar tool to xming? I will be better for me using remote applications like a local (integrated with my local desktop).

Comment: Clearly you need another monitor.  It is in the Programmer Bill of Rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day Pawel.
Could you specify your situation?

1. If you need to call and retrive exit codes from windows objects(programms and etc) remotely try to use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)

2. If you need to execute your code remotely try to use some kinds of frameworks for example [Pyro](http://irmen.home.xs4all.nl/pyro/)(it's implemented in Python programming language)

3. in case of using file systems locally you neede to can create share on client machine and mount it in your host machine

Best Regards, 
Dmitry.

Comment: Sorry for two answers...
Dmitry thanks for your answer.
I don't want to just run some applications remotely and just get the result.
I want to use graphical aplications (for example Eclipse) remotely. Just like it is done in XMING. Using applications remotely in that way it will be more convenient for me.
It is not only editing files remotely, it is also using some data base which isn't available outside remote machine.